# Best compatible firmware for my router to set bandwidth caps?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, bandwidth, firmware

I have a Linksys N300, E1200 router and it has a built in QoS functionality, but I read somewhere that QoS is like spikes, as in like turnlike and not constant (I'm sorry I don't know how to explain). I wanted to be able to manually set bandwidth caps for PCs on my home network. I saw something about setting the designated PC to a static IP and then doing something, but it wasn't well explained enough. I also saw something about setting designated PC in a different port and setting priority to that low. I think DD-WRT doesn't have a feature to manually set bandwidth caps, and my router is compatible with it. What other firmware would be the best in this situation? I saw on Tomato firmware's site that it needs a Broadcom-based router and I'm not sure if mine is that. Thank you.

Comment: I would personally, test both, and decide which one I liked best. You don't seem to sure, if DD-WRT does or does not, have the feature you require.  Information on the Linksys N300, E1200 is pretty much well documented, DD-WRT documentation on its own support, indicates if its a Broadcom device or not.

Comment: Do you know which firmware has the most flexible QoS feature?

Comment: They're all Linux. They all have the same QoS.

Comment: Oh. My current QoS feature on stock firmware is priority based. I believe DD-WRT is like that too. I'm looking for one where I can actually manually set a number cap per MAC Address. If not that, then even percentage.

Comment: Then you need a better configuration tool, not different firmware.

Comment: Won't a different firmware help me get a better configuration tool? Also, do you have any idea how one would prioritize bandwidth making a PC have a static IP and then using ports? I read something like that elsewhere.